# How to call php return function in cakephp 3 template view?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm not very familiar with this type of function (return without parameter).

```
function get_countries()
{
return [
    "AF" => __("Afganistan"),
    "AL" => __("Albania"),
    "DZ" => __("Algeria"),
    "AS" => __("American Samoa"),
    "AD" => __("Andorra"),
    "AO" => __("Angola"),
    "AI" => __("Anguilla"),
    "AQ" => __("Antarctica"),
    "AG" => __("Antigua and Barbuda"),
    "AR" => __("Argentina"),
    "AM" => __("Armenia"),
    "AW" => __("Aruba"),
    "AU" => __("Australia"),
    "AT" => __("Austria"),
    "AX" => __("Åland Islands")
    ];
}
```

How would I call this function in Cakephp template view?
Say I have 'AF' as a value to call this function in order to get 'Afganistan'.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean but, this function returns an array.

Comment: you just call this function and this will return an array. big deal?? `$var = get_countries()` now `$var` is my array with all the countries in it. $var['AF'] is my value that I want

Comment: @keaton oh right, it was just a function with an array. thanks for showing how to get the value I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get one of the elements by key would be this:

```
function get_country($country)
{
    return [
        "AF" => __("Afganistan"),
        "AL" => __("Albania"),
        "DZ" => __("Algeria"),
        "AS" => __("American Samoa"),
        "AD" => __("Andorra"),
        "AO" => __("Angola"),
        "AI" => __("Anguilla"),
        "AQ" => __("Antarctica"),
        "AG" => __("Antigua and Barbuda"),
        "AR" => __("Argentina"),
        "AM" => __("Armenia"),
        "AW" => __("Aruba"),
        "AU" => __("Australia"),
        "AT" => __("Austria"),
        "AX" => __("Åland Islands")
    ][$country];
}
```

If you want to have your code a bit more clean and reusable, split keep your function as posted and add another one:

```
function get_country($country)
{
    return get_countries()[$country];
}
```

You may also write `return get_countries()[$country] ?? ''` if you cannot be sure that there is a country for each input value. It will simply return an empty string then.

Comment: how would I do this in a cakephp template view? is it possible?

Comment: <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($countries as $country) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $country->country; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $country->clicks; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;
                    unset($country); ?>
                    </tbody>

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: with above code in template view, I'm getting say "AF" as a country instead of Afganistan. I want the full country name, not a code.

Comment: Then simply replace the `<?= $country->country; ?>` part with `<?= get_country($country->country); ?>` after declaring above functions.